# Continue to retrieve data even the result is null C#

Tags: c#

I have a program that will retrieve student and class information.

I already use `if (!reader.HasRows)` to check if the student is existing but the problem is not all student is already registered in a certain class and I want it continue retrieving data even the values in the class information is Null. I am new to C# and any help and recommendation is deeply appreciated.

```
    private void btnstudsearch_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"data source = DELL-USER\SQLEXPRESS;integrated security = SSPI;database = Enrollment System");

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = null;

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select tbl_studregs.fname, tbl_studregs.mname, tbl_studregs.lname, tbl_studregs.age, tbl_studregs.sex, 
        tbl_studregs.address, tbl_studregs.gname, tbl_studregs.gcnum, tbl_studregs.educlevel, tbl_class.yglevel, tbl_class.section from tbl_studregs 
            inner join tbl_class on tbl_studregs.classid = tbl_class.classid where tbl_studregs.studid = @id ", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", txtstudsearch.Text);

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (!reader.HasRows)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Student not found! Please recheck the student ID!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            ClearAllTextBox();
        }
        else 
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                txtstudfname.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
                txtmname.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                txtstudlname.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                txtage.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                cboxsex.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                rtxtaddress.Text = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();

                txtgname.Text = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                txtgcnum.Text = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                cboxstudlevel.Text = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                txtstudyearlev.Text = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
                txtstudsec.Text = reader.GetValue(10).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a C# question, this is a SQL question. Look into the other ways you can join on tables.

Comment: "_I already use "if (!reader.HasRows)" to check if the student is existing but the problem is not all student is already registered in a certain class and **I want it continue retrieving data even the values in the class information is Null**._"   Then change your SQL query...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is not a discussion forum, it is a Question and Answer site where you can ask a **specific** programming question that **can be answered** rather than discussed. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and then edit your question to conform with the site guidelines. Off-topic questions such as this one are routinely closed, but if edited to ask an *answerable* question, can be re-opened again. Thanks.

Comment: @TyCobb your right! I am not aware of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to retrieve the information for a student even if there isn't a class connected to them on the tbl_class table. I think it would help most you to look up the [difference between different SQL join operations](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

It looks like what you want is a `left join` instead of an `inner join` in your SQL query, although it may depend on what your database looks like.